# Getting 'Failed to install one or more provisioning profiles on this device' on Xcode 14.2

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I'm using
macOS Ventura 13.2.1,
iOS 16.1,
and Xcode 14.2.

I have already added certificate to the keychain. When I try to add provisioning profile to by Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> right click on connected device -> Show provisioning profiles -> and then I select the correct provisioning profile. I get this error:

> 'Failed to install one or more provisioning profiles on this device. Please ensure the provisioning profile is configured for this device. If not, please try to generate a new profile'.

I tried various things like re-downloading certificate and provisioning profile, re-adding certificate to keychain, unpairing and re-pairing iPhone.

Comment: Unless you are doing something special then there is no reason to manually try to install a provisioning profile on a device. Enable "Automatically manage signing" and select a Team for your project and Xcode will do what it needs.

Comment: @HangarRash, well, i faced same issue, and "Automatically manage signing" didnt work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It finally worked by these steps. Open finder and from the left panel under `locations`, select you paired device. It will start loading data. Once done, try adding the provisioning profile. Then click on the `sync` button on right bottom corner. Also open finder and press `Command`+`Shif`+`G` and paste this path `users/YourUser/Library/MobileDevice/ProvisioningProfiles`. Verify the provisioning profiles are added there as well.

Comment: Worked for me using Xcode 14.3.1